# Hiearchical agglomerative clustering with >3 features

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science, hierarchical-clustering

**Introduction**

I am trying to confirm that my understanding of how the Hierarchical Agglomerative clustering in python works is indeed correct. So, for a panda DataFrame where I have MxN (M = rows and N = columns), where M is a feature being measured and N is a patient.

In my case I have **83 features (m1, m2,...,m83)** and **6 patients (n1,n2,..,n6)**. So for each patient I measure 83 features and I am interested in which of the features are overrepresented and underrepresented for each patient individually as well as grouping patients together based on the representation of these features. So, I am doing this by performing a Hierarchical Agglomerative Clustering outputting a heatmap with an associated dendrogram using the Seaborn package.

So, most examples usually include a MxN matrix where N=2 and M could be of any size. In this case this would be represented in a graph as our two columns being our x,y coordinates in a 2-dimensional graph. Adding an extra patient/column would be adding an extra, z parameter in my coordinate system leading to a 3-dimensional graph with coordinates x,y,z for each patient/column for all M features measured.

**Example of the Panda DataFrame.**

Previewing only the first and last 3 rows and columns.

(Pdb) feature_df

```
       Patient1   Patient2  Patient3   Patient4   Patient5   Patient6

Feature1   4.686681   1.718879  0.772530   2.085830   2.755356   2.549348

Feature2   1.605639   1.098595  0.000000   0.084507  19.267667   4.056351

Feature3   0.000000   0.063615  0.010603   0.000000   0.005301   0.037109
...             ...        ...       ...        ...        ...        ...
Feature81  0.213393   0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.106696   0.000000

Feature82  2.628437   2.813818  0.933526   2.416573   0.695179   2.078915

Feature83  0.000000   0.000000  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000


[83 rows x 6 columns]
```

**The code**

I perform a log2 conversion of all raw values (the raw value is a count value for each feature, i.e. A frequency) for all raw values that were 0 (after log2 conversion become -inf but are replaced with 0) are masked in the heatmap but are obviously included in the clustering analysis.

```
feature_df = pd.DataFrame(features, columns=sample_list, index=gene_expression_list)
feature_df.applymap(np.log2).replace(float('-inf'),0)
mask = feature_df.isin(values=[0])
sns.clustermap(feature_df, metric="euclidean", method="ward", 
mask=mask, cmap="Blues")
plt.show()
```

[image: Heatmap of clustered features]

**The question**

1. Is my above understanding correct?
2. If so, for datasets with >3 dimensions (3 patients) what distance methods are considered to be effective as I am assuming that the Euclidean distance distance would not be the most representable?
3. Lastly, If my understanding is correct I can see how a dendrogram can be created to cluster the features/rows but I cannot see how a dendrogram is created to cluster the patients/columns into various groups.

Any advice, suggestions or thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Is there anyone that is able to answer any of the questions posed or if not at least engage in a discussion regarding the questions even if you are not entirely sure of the right answer. I believe both of which would be valuable for me and other users.